# Container div not covering entire page

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason my `container` div isn't covering the entire page. It may be worth noting that I am using the Bootstrap gem. How can I make this div take up the entire HTML page?

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<div class="container">
<head>
  <title>dylan e. richards</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>


</head>
<body>
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
       <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
  <% end %>

  <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>
  <% if !current_user %>
    <%= link_to 'admin login', new_user_session_path, class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs' %> 
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, class: 'btn btn-xs btn-default' %>


  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>


</body>
</div> <!-- END container -->
</html>
```

styles.css.scss

```
nav {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.navspan {
    width: auto;
    height:3px;
    background-color: #333;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.postdate {
    text-align: center
}

btn-primary {
    background-color: #000
}

.container {
    font-family: "Droid Serif", "serif";
    background-color: #FDFBF5;
}



.highlight {
    color: #1abc9c;
 }


.underline {
    color: #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f39c12;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;

}

 #post {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 42.5em;
 }


 .posttitle {

    text-align: center;
 }


.span {
    background-color: #f39c12;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

 .postdate {
    text-align: center;
    color: #999;
 }



 a:link {color:#16a085;}      /* unvisited link */
 a:visited {color:#2c3e50;}   /* visited link */
 a:hover {color:#1abc9c;}     /* mouse over link */
 a:active {color:#0000FF;}    /* selected link */
```

Comment: We need to see the output HTML.

Comment: Hi, Paulie. What exactly is output HTML? If it helps, the page I'm working on is the index of http://dylanerichards.com

Comment: what's wrong with container there? you want it to touch the bottom of the screen?

Comment: I'd like the container to cover the entire browser window.

Answer (score 2):

Place `<div class="container">` after the `<body>` tag and move the corresponding `</div>` tag so that it is inside `</body>`.

Answer (score 1):

move `</div> <!-- END container -->` BEFORE `</body>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your div "container" inside the body and you

Answer (score 0):

To fill the whole page in bootstrap you will need to use the `container-fluid` class on the div

`<div class="container">`

becomes

`<div class="container-fluid">`

You will want to put your `<div>` inside your `<body>` as well